# Transparent background after warp operation that rotate the image

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject a georeference image using gdalwarp (and after directly in c++). The reprojection implies a rotation, so the resulting image has a black background where I want to have a transparent background.

The best I could find was to run something like that:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata 255 -t_srs EPSG:4326 test.kap test.tif
```

But this also remove black pixels in the middle of the map.

I have also tried many other things and options without any luck.

Is there a way to achieve this? If not is there a way to calculate the raster "footprint" so I can use it as a mask to hide pixels with no data?

---

I have tried many options including:

```
gdalwarp -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:4326 test.kap test.tif
```

The result is that the background is transparent but the map itself is just plain green (as I can see in QGIS).

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Could you add some examples of what other options you've tried.  It'll help others find a solution faster for you if they know you've tried something already.

Comment: I have tried a lot to play with dstalpha and various values for the no data parameters, both for dst and src. I have also tried the same thing using gdal c++ api but the best I could achieve was to replace black pixels with transparent ones, for all the pixels and not only those outside the map. I didn't succeed to get a working alpha band.

Comment: It sounds like it may be an issue with how QGIS interprets a 2 band image. A couple of things to try: use `gdalwarp` with the argument `-co PROFILE=GeoTIFF` _without_ the `-dstalpha` argument. Also, try using `gdal_translate` with `-expand rgba` to convert the file to a GTIff and then use `gdalwarp` to reproject that GTiff.

Comment: Alpha channel should be the right way do it but now your client does not seem to treat it right. Could you share a small sample image with alpha for testing?  Or at least gdalinfo report to start with. You can also read http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html and try -dstnodata next. If you have totally black (0) or white (255) pixels in the data they will come transparent as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help
-co Profile=GeoTIFF didn't work: I ended up with a black background again. But going first with gdal_translate -expand rgba first and then just gdalwarp (without any particular options) did the job! So I guess the reason is that the source file must have an alpha channel? The test.kap file can be found here if you want to try: http://www.virtual-winds.org/maitai/test.kap

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, one way to solve this issue is to first convert the image to a multi-band image using `gdal_translate` with the `-expand rgba` argument and then use `gdalwarp` to repoject that image.

I'm not familiar with the BSB/KAP format, but it looks like it's an indexed format (it uses a color palette). The `-dstalpha` argument of `gdalwarp` simply adds another band to hold an alpha channel (according to the [docs](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)).
It sounds like that's causing the output image to have 2 bands, one indexed RGB band and 1 alpha and QGIS doesn't know what to do with the indexed band.

I'm not sure that this is the perfect solution, your output file is likely much larger than the input, but it does function at least. You may want to look at [compression options](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) when using `gdal_translate` if the file size is an issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit difficult. I have potentially thousands of those files and I dont want to pre-reproject them all before being able to show something, especially if it takes ages and takes a lot of disk space. What I really want in the end is crop/resize/reproject on the fly directly in c++. It seems a bit difficult if on top of that it has to convert a 1 RGB color-indexed band into a 4 bands RGBA geotiff. Anyway I will continue investigating, thanks again.

Comment: Finally after much tries and errors, I got it working in plain C++. I can take a rotated geoimage, crop a part of it and reproject it, with a transparent background. You were right, in fact -dstalpha works correctly and it is just that QGIS isn't expecting a 2 bands raster with the second one being an alpha band. Many thanks to all.

Comment: @PhilippeLelong You should post your C++ version as an answer; it's completely valid to answer your own questions.

Comment: -expand rgba worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

So the conclusion is that one can use directly gdalwarp API in c++, configuring options with something like that:

```
-te -74.7889397212 29.8376582422 -59.5466673500 43.9055342993 -ts 0 2448 -of MEM -multi -r near -t_srs +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs -dstalpha
```

In my case that will add an alpha band (so we will end up with 2 bands), after that it is just a matter of reading that alpha band and applying it to the resulting image (something that QGIS does not know how to handle).

Basically my code for that (still in development, Qt style) looks like that:

```
    if(warped->GetRasterCount() == 2 && warped->GetRasterBand(2)->GetColorInterpretation() == GCI_AlphaBand) {
    alpha = QImage(imgSizeActual, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    warped->GetRasterBand(2)->RasterIO(GF_Read, portionRaster.topLeft().x(), portionRaster.topLeft().y(),
                                       qAbs(portionRaster.width()), qAbs(portionRaster.height()),
                                       alpha.bits(),
                                       imgSizeActual.width(), imgSizeActual.height(),
                                       GDT_Byte, 1, alpha.width(), &extraArg);
    hasAlpha = true;
} ... and later
if(hasAlpha) {
    image.setAlphaChannel(alpha);
}
```

Thanks to all for helping me to understand this

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at adding an alpha band.

With `gdalwarp` this can be achieved with the `-dstalpha` switch.

Details can be found [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I have tried many options including that one:
    gdalwarp -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:4326 test.kap test.tif
The result is that the background is transparent... but the map itself is just plain green (as I can see in QGis).